# how do I resume an scp download?

Tags: scp

I started downloading about 1gb from a colleague, and received 750mb in about 8 hours.

The command I used was

```
$ scp dev@dev_server:/home/dev/trainingVM/Centos7VMa_app_zxTmw457.ova
```

What command could I use next, so that the remainder would download in under 3 hours, not 10?

Comment: Do you **have** to use `scp`?

Answer (score 4):

Use rsync to complete the transfer, e.g.:

```bsh
rsync --partial -e ssh dev@dev_server:/home/dev/trainingVM/Centos7VMa_app_zxTmw457.ova \
   /path/to/local/Centos7VMa_app_zxTmw457.ova
```

The `--partial` option is useful in case the transfer is interrupted again before completion.  It tells `rsync` not to delete any partially transferred files.

If you want verbose output, progress display, and/or stats at the end of the transfer, use the `-v`, `--progress`, `--stats`.   Also use the `--human` or `-h` **twice** for "human-readable" (i.e. use KB, MB, GB instead of just bytes).

```
rsync -v --progress --stats -h -h --partial -e ssh \
    dev@dev_server:/home/dev/trainingVM/Centos7VMa_app_zxTmw457.ova \
    /path/to/local/Centos7VMa_app_zxTmw457.ova
```

Comment: No `--append` or `--append-verify` needed?

Comment: Nope, not needed.  The files aren't the same size (or mod-time), so `rsync` will compare the checksums of blocks in both source & target and transfer only what it needed to sync the target with the source.  `--append` is for files that are continuously growing (like log files) and according to the man page "The use of --append can be dangerous if you aren't 100% sure that all the files in the transfer are shared, growing files."

Comment: Downside of this is that if the rsync is interrupted before the new file has reached the size of the existing, it will replace the old file with the new, effectively reducing the amount transferred. I don't have a good solution for this issue but it's burned me a couple of times on large files and slow links

Comment: @roaima that's not how rsync behaves in my experience. In fact, i just tested it by transferring a 22MB text file, truncating the copy to 5MB, and the rsyncing it again.  Interrupted it with ^C partway through, and the copy was 13MB.  Ran rsync again and it sent the remainder of the 22MB.  the  `--stats` option will even tell you how much it sent, and how much the transfer was sped up due to rsync.

Comment: File 100MB. Transfer 70MB and stop. Retransfer only 50MB and stop. New partial is now only 50MB

Comment: that's odd.  were you using `--partial`? do you have it aliased to have other default options? what version? I'm currently running `rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31`, but I've had the same behaviour for as long as I've been using rsync (over 20 years)....I just tried it again with a 600MB file, with multiple interruptions - no problems. each time I restarted rsync it restarted where it left off.